# Selenium IDE. Cross-process JS call failed on click command

Tags: angularjs, selenium, automated-tests, selenium-ide

I have a SPA on AngularJS 1 and Selenium IDE 2.9.1 for functional testing.

There is button with onclick handler on a form.
When I run some test scenario it crashes on click command on this button with message:

```
[error] Unexpected Exception: Error: cross-process JS call faild.
```

But the SPA reacts properly and do what it needs to do.

Next tests pass correctly, except one. So, I have no `green light`.

How can I handle this click`s behavior?  Or what am I doing wrong?

Even If I call this button via keyPress with code 13 I have the same situation

```
·  [info] Executing: |keyPress | css=button | \13 |

·  [debug] Command found, going to execute keyPress

·  [debug] modifyWindow seleniumMarker1485501036924:selenium1485501041612

·  [debug] _getFrameElement: frameElement=null

·  [debug] modifySeparateTestWindowToDetectPageLoads: already polling this window: selenium1485501041612

·  [debug] getCurrentWindow newPageLoaded = false

·  [error] Unexpected Exception: Error: cross-process JS call failed.

·  [debug] commandError

·  [debug] testComplete: failed=true

·  [info] Test case failed
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue could be the last Firefox released version. As I saw on these links:

- https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3435
- https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/selenium-users/4Jz6hIjjxNk

There are two solutions:

- Downgrade last version to the 50.0.1 release, in which the error was not thrown
- Install Selenium IDE: Flow Control extension to Firefox